# Partial derivative of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, quantum-mechanics

Given $n=(x + iy)/\sqrt{2}L$ and $\overline n=(x - iy)/\sqrt{2}L$.

$\partial_n=\partial/\partial n$, $\partial_x=\partial/\partial x$, $\partial_y=\partial/\partial y$

Show that $\partial_n$ = $L(\partial_x - i \partial_y)/\sqrt{2}$  and  $\partial_\overline n$ = $L(\partial_x + i \partial_y)/\sqrt{2}$.

I'm not sure on how to start proving these but should I use the definition for the Wirtinger derivatives?

[image]

If ever I use that, how can $\sqrt2 L$ be in the numberator? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the Wirtinger derivatives, but do know that the Wirtinger derivatives are derived the same way when we do not have the $\sqrt{2}L$ factor present. Anyways, notice that we can redefine $x$ and $y$ in terms of $n$ and $\bar{n}$:

$$x(n,\bar{n}) = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}(n + \bar{n})$$

$$y(n,\bar{n}) = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}i}(n - \bar{n})$$

We are going to need the partial derivatives:

$$\partial_nx = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}, \hspace{.5cm} \partial_\bar{n}x = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\partial_ny = -\frac{iL}{\sqrt{2}}, \hspace{.5cm} \partial_\bar{n}y = \frac{iL}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Now take any function in terms of $x$ and $y$ and parametrize it:

$$f(x,y) = f(x(n,\bar{n}),y(n,\bar{n}))$$

and find the derivatives using the chain rule:

$$\partial_nf = \partial_xf \partial_nx + \partial_yf \partial_ny = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}\partial_xf - i\frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}\partial_yf = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}(\partial_x - i\partial_y)f$$

$$\partial_\bar{n}f = \partial_xf \partial_\bar{n}x + \partial_yf \partial_\bar{n}y = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}\partial_xf + i\frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}\partial_yf = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}(\partial_x + i\partial_y)f$$

The last step is to notice that we are operating on the same scalar function on both sides. Therefore, the operators acting on both sides must be equivalent giving the desired result:

$$\partial_n = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}(\partial_x - i\partial_y)$$

$$\partial_\bar{n} = \frac{L}{\sqrt{2}}(\partial_x + i\partial_y)$$

Comment: Why did you took the partial derivative with respect to $\overline n$ on the right side while on the left is n? Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: If you are referencing where I took the partial derivatives, i just listed both partial derivatives on a single line for $x$ and the ones for $y$ on the second line. We need all four derivatives in the following calculations which is why i explicitly wrote them down. If you are asking why some of them are not the same like in the case of $y$, you should take into account the negative sign.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the comma between the equations. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's actually my bad...I gave it more space now to make it more clear.